# Using kubectl to grep multiple pod/service logs for a specific phrase

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I have a bunch of services deployed to a Kubernetes cluster (various pods and services all load-balanced behind a gateway). I am making a REST call to one of them and getting unexpected errors, but the problem is I'm not actually sure *which* pod/service is actually throwing the error. I would like to check all the logs of every pod/service.

When I run `kubectl get namespace` I get:

```
NAME               STATUS     AGE
another-app        Active     22d
myapp              Active     22d
myapp-database     Active     22d
default            Active     22d
kube-public        Active     22d
kube-system        Active     22d
zanzabar           Active     22d
```

Is there a `kubectl log` command that can scan the entire cluster for logs and search them for a specific error message? For instance, say the error message I'm getting back from the REST (`curl`) is "Sorry mario your princess is in another castle". Is there any way I can use `kubectl log` to scan all pod/service logs for that phrase and display the results back to me? If not, then whats the best/easiest way **using `kubectl`** to find the pod/service with the error message (and hopefully, more details behind my error)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fetch the logs of a particular pod or container(use -c flag for container) and grep the error logs by pipelining the log command with the grep command.

For example if I want to get logs of a pod with name my-pod and want to grep "error exists" word then command goes like:

```
kubectl logs my-pod | grep “error exist”
```

Refer this [document](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/cheatsheet/#interacting-with-running-pods) for multiple ways of fetching logs and this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53348331/extract-lines-from-kubernetes-log) for more information on grep usage.